# passing arguments to ode45 with 'flag'

Tags: matlab

I want to pass additional parameters to the ode45 function in MATLAB. There are many questions already on this, but I also have a 'flag' argument in my function.

```
function [xdot,isterminal,dircn]=spp(t,x,flag,f)
```

Usually, while calling ode45, something like this would work if spp did not have a flag argument.

```
options=odeset('RelTol',1e-13,'AbsTol',1e-14,'events','on');
[t,x,te,xe,ie]=ode45(@(t,x)spp(t,x,f),[0 2*pi/OMEG],[xin;xdin],options);
```

I have searched around but cannot find the solution. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not exactly know how to treat 'flags' but usually when I need to pass extra variables to the ode I define them as 'global' in the main .m file and also in the file where I define the function I give to the ode.

Or you might use the varargin function .

Comment: Yes, that did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply pass flag the way you are passing f?

```
[t,x,te,xe,ie]=ode45(@(t,x)spp(t,x,flag,f),[0 2*pi/OMEG],[xin;xdin],options);
```

(Global variables in MATLAB often cause problems and it is best to avoid them, if possible.)

Maybe I'm missing something here?

Comment: flag is not a variable I am allowed to pass. The value of flag is decided by ode45 function at every iteration.

Comment: Are you talking about "flag" in the ode *output* function? The output function is not the same function as the "odefun." You have not defined an output function.

Comment: No, I am not using an output function. I am using flag as an argument to a user defined function, the value of which will be updated by ode45. I think it is allowed.